# Python Pandas Subset Hex String, Convert to Decimal

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I've got a dataframe. Column B contains 4-character hexidecimal values:

```
dict = {'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'B': ['1346', '0f46', '5a46']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

I am only interested in the first two characters of the hex in Column B. 
I want to replace Column B with the only the first two characters in the hex, and then convert them to decimal.

So the end result should be a data frame that looks like this:

```
A    B
foo  19
bar  15
baz  90
```

I can't even figure how to get the first two characters sub-setted. This seems like it should work, but it doesn't:

```
df.B.str[:2]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice the column using `str[:2]` and then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html#pandas.Series.apply) and use a lambda to convert the hex to decimal:

```
In [255]:    
df['B'] = df['B'].str[:2].apply(lambda x: int(x,16))
df

Out[255]:
     A   B
0  foo  19
1  bar  15
2  baz  90
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a stylistic difference, but instead of using a lambda you could also pass the keyword argument `base` for [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) directly to [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str[:2].apply(int, base=16)
```